# I really, don't even know how to frame question for this problem

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

So, here's the thing, I have class something like this with **81 Strings:**

```
class Dinner{
      static String drinks = "Coctail";
      static String food1 = "pizza";
      static String food2 = "Meat Ball";
      static String desserts = "Cake";
                 ..
                 ..
                 ..
                 ..
                 ..
                 [81 Strings]
 }
```

**User Selects one item from the drop down**, this dropdown has all the above Strings like drinks,food1,food2,desserts

Now, I need to add this selected items values to the database, eg. **if user selects "drinks" then i need to add "cocktail", to the database**.

My DB post call looks something Like this:

```
await http.post(
    body: jsonEncode({
         "item": Dinner.drinks,
         })
          );
```

here in, "Dinner.drinks", **drinks will change dynamically**, **because if user selects food1, then it be taken as "Dinner.food1"**

**Is these a way to insert data dynamically** according the selection from dropdown?

Comment: Considered using a Map<String, String> as data structure instead of this massive `Dinner` class?

Comment: Thanks, it will work, Just a simple turn around and creative way of thinking in different angle.Write this as the answer, I will accept this answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your problem can be solved by rethinking the data structure. I don't know the full use case of this but it seems to be a case where a `Map<String, String>` would fit (maybe combined with an enum as key).

Another good thing about `Map` is that it is a lot easier to iterate over all the key-value pairs with e.g. [`yourMap.entries`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.1/dart-core/Map/entries.html).